# How do I prevent someone from writing if his data doesnt contain a specific key?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I am new to firebase database and I want to add a rule that can prevent someone from writing if his data doesnt contain a specific key.

my firebase database rules:
[image]

.

**In this image**:

[image]

the 1ST key only contains 1 childkey named "sample"
and the 2ND key contains a lot of keys like days, date, user, downloads, etc.

Is it possible to add a rule that prevents the 1ST key from writing if it doesn't contain a childkey named "date"?

I hope someone helps me, Thanks!

Comment: For future reference, it is really helpful if you include your data structure in the question instead of linking out. Most helpful if you can even provide the data as copy/pastable code in the post.

Comment: @Dennis Alund, Thanks for the tip, i will do that next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can definitely create a rule that validates the presence of a child key.

And there is also a language tool called [Firebase Bolt](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/bolt) that can simplify your rules writing. It helps a lot when you want to make more complicated validations and checks on your data.

```
{
  "rules": {
    "posts": {
      "$postId": {
        ".validate": "newData.hasChildren(['date'])"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello sir, i'm really new to this and i don't understand what "$postId" is, should i just leave it like that in the rules?

Comment: Check out [the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/#section-overview) for how to write security rules.

Comment: The `$postId` is a wildcard. It means that the rules under it (so the `.validate` here) apply to each child node of `posts`.

Comment: Thank you so much guys for the help, i am grateful.